# Show the change in the rules only after the first rule is ok

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let reg = /[A-Z]/;
document.querySelector(".password__input").addEventListener("input", function(){
if(document.querySelector(".password__input").value.length < 10) {
document.querySelector(".rule__length").style.color = "red";
} else if (reg.test(document.querySelector(".password__input").value == false)) {
document.querySelector(".rule__capital").style.color = "red";
}
});
```

```html
<p class="form-input form-input__password">
  <label class="password label password__input-label" for="password">Пароль</label>
  <input class="password input password__input password__input-first" maxlength="250" type="password" name="user-password" id="password" required="">
</p>
<div class="password-rules">
  <h4 class="rules-heading">Password should have</h4>
  <ul class="list-reset rules-list">
      <li class="rule rule__length"> at least 10 symbols</li>


      <li class="rule rule__capital">a capital letter</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have an input with a password and 2 rules which the password should follow, for instance it should be:

1. 10 symbols long
2. Should have at least one capital letter

If one of the rules is being followed, it should turn green, if not - red.

The problem here is that I need to change the color of the rules while typing in the input but at the same time only after one of the rules is being approved, for example:

1. I start typing "adsasa" - the color of the rules is still grey
2. I add "A" - the color of the second rule turns green (the first one is still grey)
3. I add some more symbols  - now both rules are green, and starting from this point if the rules are being changed and become incorrect they turn red (and if they are changed again and become correct they turn green).

Is there any way to do smth like this? Usual eventListeners like "change" and "input" are not working for me :(

Answer (score 1):

You had a few mistakes in your code such as 
`else if (reg.test(document.querySelector(".password__input").value == false))`
should have been `else if (reg.test(document.querySelector(".password__input").value) == false)` and `document.querySelector(".password__input").addEventListener("input", function(){` there is no such event such as `input`, i've fixed upo your code a bit using the `keyup` event, I hope it helps

```js
let reg = /[A-Z]/;
let pInput = document.querySelector(".password__input");
let ruleLenght= document.querySelector(".rule__length");
let ruleCapital= document.querySelector(".rule__capital");

pInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
if(pInput.value.length < 10) {
  ruleLenght.style.color = "red";
  ruleCapital.style.color = "red";
}else{
  ruleLenght.style.color = "green";
  if(!reg.test(pInput.value)){
    ruleCapital.style.color = "red";
  }else{
    ruleCapital.style.color = "green";
  }
}
});
```

```html
<p class="form-input form-input__password">
  <label class="password label password__input-label" for="password">Пароль</label>
  <input class="password input password__input password__input-first" maxlength="250" type="password" name="user-password" id="password" required="">
</p>
<div class="password-rules">
  <h4 class="rules-heading">Password should have</h4>
  <ul class="list-reset rules-list">
      <li class="rule rule__length"> at least 10 symbols</li>
      <li class="rule rule__capital">a capital letter</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the corrections!

Unfortunately, in this case the rules change their color immediately as well, but I need them to wait till the first rule gets right and only then start changing the color. Is it possible?

Comment: @MikeL. I think this answer does this and you should accept it!